Disable access to WooCommerce Admin Payments page for specific users
I have this code to disable/remove the payments tab from the WooCommerce settings tab, however, the users can still directly access the payments settings / payment methods using the direct url like wp-admin/admin.php?page=wc-settings&tab=checkout
add_filter( 'woocommerce_settings_tabs_array', 'wd_remove_woocommerce_payment_tab', 200, 1 );
function wd_remove_woocommerce_payment_tab( $tabs_array ) {
    
    $wd_allowed_users = array("asd", "asd", "asd");
    $wd_user = wp_get_current_user();
    if ( in_array(strtolower($wd_user->user_login), $wd_allowed_users)){
        unset( $tabs_array['checkout'] );
    }
    return $tabs_array;
}


You can try the following, that will redirect the non-allowed users to WooCommerce Admin General settings, when trying to access WooCommerce Admin Payments page:
add_action( 'woocommerce_init', 'role_based_redirect' );
function role_based_redirect() {
    global $pagenow, $current_user;

    // Define allowed users below
    $non_allowed_users = array("abc", "afi", "asd");

    // Targetting WooCommerce Admin Payments page
    if ( is_admin() && $pagenow === 'admin.php' && isset($_GET['page'],$_GET['tab']) 
    && $_GET['page'] === 'wc-settings' && $_GET['tab'] === 'checkout' 
    && in_array( strtolower($current_user->user_login), $non_allowed_users ) )
    {
        wp_redirect( admin_url( 'admin.php?page=wc-settings' ) );
        exit();
    }
}

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin).

I have used the following code, similar to what LoicTheAztec have suggested above and that resolved it. Pasting it here, just in case someone needs that.
add_action( 'admin_init', 'wd_redirect_from_payments_tab' );
function wd_redirect_from_payments_tab() {
    global $pagenow;

    $wd_allowed_users = array("asd", "asf", "wer");
    $wd_user = wp_get_current_user();

    if ( ! in_array(strtolower($wd_user->user_login), $wd_allowed_users)){
        if( $pagenow == 'admin.php' && isset( $_GET['page'] ) && $_GET['page'] == 'wc-settings' && $_GET['tab'] == 'checkout'  ) {
            wp_redirect( admin_url( '/admin.php?page=wc-settings&tab=general' ) );
            exit;
        }
    }
}

